# Cannot cast IEnumerable<ViewmodelA> to IEnumerable<ViewmodelB>

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, viewmodel

I retrieve a list with the type of `IEnumerable<ViewmodelA>` and need to cast this list to `IEnumerable<ViewmodelB>`. There are same and different properties in each `viewmodel` and I just want to map the same properties (Name and Surnmame). Is it possible using boxing or `AutoMapper`? I tried boxing but it is not working :(

```
IEnumerable<ViewmodelB> newList;
newList = (IEnumerable<ViewmodelB>)demoService.GetList(); //returns IEnumerable<ViewmodelA>
```

***ViewodelA:***

```
public class ViewmodelA {

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public string School { get; set; }

    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

***ViewodelB:***

```
public class ViewmodelB {

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public string Work { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You can't "cast" things that are of different or incompatible types. You can "convert" them though, but only if a sensible conversion exists. Why do you think you can convert these objects?

Comment: "I tried boxing"???? Can you please explain what that means in relation to code shown in the post? ( there are no `struct` shown - so where exactly do you expect boxing to happen?)

Comment: @Enigmativity Because there is a service retrieving a list in `IEnumerable<ViewmodelA>` and I want to use this method. On the other hand I have some extra properties and do not want to modify ViewmodelA as it is a general usage viewmodel.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov `(IEnumerable<ViewmodelB>)demoService.GetList()`

Comment: @hexadecimal Sorry, what that line suppose to mean? Was it some sort of reply to my question about "boxing"?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I thought (IEnumerable<ViewmodelB>) is boxing for demoService.GetList() that returns IEnumerable<ViewmodelA>. Am I wrong?

Comment: `newList = demoService.GetList().Cast<ViewmodelB>();`

Comment: @hexadecimal this is not boxing... https://www.bing.com/search?q=boxing+vs+casting+c%23

Comment: use inheritance if you want to use both

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanks. What about solution of the problem?

Comment: @MaheshWaghmare I tried but unfortunately throws error like "Object with the type of ViewmodelA cannot be assigned object with the type of ViewmodelB". Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For something so trivial as this operation I think I would just:

```
var modelbs = modelas.Select(
  a => new Viewmodelb(){
    Name = a.Name,
    Surname = a.Surname
  }
);
```

You could make both viewmodels inherit from a base that has the Name and Surname in it, though note that this wouldn't allow you to cast a modela into a modelb, you could only cast the modela into the base class.

Or you could provide a constructor in modelb that takes a modela object and pulls just the name/surname out of it and use it like:

```
var modelbs = modelas.Select(
  a => new Viewmodelb(a)
);
```

Your class ViewmodelB would look like:

```
public class ViewmodelB {

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public string Work { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }

    public ViewmodelB(ViewmodelA x){
      Name = x.Name;
      Surname = x.Surname;

      //maybe initialize other properties here
    }
}
```

Comment: Yesi I was looking something like that. But I have no idea if it works for `IEnumerable<modela>` ? Any idea?

Comment: It'll work for anything you like; you're just asking LINQ to run a loop over a bunch of model a objects and stuff a new modelb into a collection, where the name and surname props have been united from the model a values. This isn't casting or boxing

Comment: For my situation **provide a constructor in modelb that takes a modelb object and pulls just the name/surname out of it** seem to be better. How can I do this? Could you pls update answer including this by using ViewmodelA and ViewmodelB? Thanks...

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to cast `ViewmodelA` to `ViewmodelB`.

The first few options that come to my mind are:

- make both classes inherit from the same base class,
- make both classes implement an interface,
- create a conversion mechanism between `A` and `B`.

Comment: *"Create a conversion mechanism between A and B."*. But how? Any example pls?

Comment: Any reply please?

Answer (score 0):

You can only do:

```
IEnumerable<ViewmodelB> newList = demoService.GetList().Select(a => SomeMethodCreatingBFromA(a));
```

Where `SomeMethodCreatingBFromA` can be anything - call constructor, AutoMapper, whatever. Didn't use AutoMapper to much, but I suppose it has a method that converts between collections.

Comment: Seems to be good approach. Any example for SomeMethodCreatingBFromA? Could you post pls?

Comment: ViewModelB SomeMethodCreatingBFromA(ViewModelA a)
{
    return new ViewModelB()
    {
        Name = a.Name,
        Surname = a.Surname,
        ...
    };
}

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use the common properties, create a base class or an interface, where you define the common properties and derive both classes from that. Then you can use the base class or interface.

Answer (score 0):

Here are examples for [@tymtam answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58928425/3563013)

1. Make both classes inherit from the same base class
2. Make both classes implement an interface
3. Create a conversion mechanism between A and B

{

```
/// <summary>
/// Using the same base class
/// </summary>
public class BaseClass
{
    public string Property { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModelA : BaseClass
{
    public string Property { get; set; }
}
public class ViewModelB : BaseClass
{
    public string Property { get; set; }
}


/// <summary>
/// Using the same interface
/// </summary>
public interface BaseInterface
{
    string Property { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModelA : BaseInterface
{
    public string Property { get; set; }
}
public class ViewModelB : BaseInterface
{
    public string Property { get; set; }
}


/// <summary>
/// Create a conversion mechanism. This can be done in either in ViewModelA or ViewModelB
/// </summary>

public class ViewModelA
{
    public string Property { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator ViewModelA(ViewModelB model) => new ViewModelA { Property = model.Property };
    public static implicit operator ViewModelB(ViewModelA model) => new ViewModelB { Property = model.Property };
}
public class ViewModelB
{
    public string Property { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I cannot edit ViewmodelA and modify its inheritance.

Comment: Then use the third method, `implicit operator`

Comment: Many thanks for your helps. I used the previous method as Caius Jard suggested. Thanks and voted up ;)